# angular toggle n-click function calling

Tags: javascript, angularjs

is there a way to toggle the ng-click value on a button, but when the value is a function?

use something similar to toggle classes :
ng-class:"funtionToggle?'disabled':'enabled'"

but when the value is a function: 
ng-click="funnyFunction()"

I want to execute funnyFunction() if the user select certain options in a form, and execute seriousFunction() if the user select different ones, but I need to use the same button, just change the function that will be called depending on the user interaction.

Comment: Question is confusing as to exactly what you are trying to do. What does *"change the function that will be called depending on the user interaction"* mean?

Answer (score 1):

yes you can, but not like you want to do it. Don't write your logic in html, write it in javascript, like this:

```
<button ng-click="someFunction()">Click here</button>
```

and in javascript:

```
$scope.someFunction() {
  if($scope.form.someOption) {
    funnyFunction();
  } else {
    seriousFunction();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ng-click="this[method]()"`

```
  <form action="">
    <input ng-click="sendFunctionName(choice.select)" ng-model="choice.select" type="radio" name="gender" value="function1"> Function1<br>
    <input ng-click="sendFunctionName(choice.select)" ng-model="choice.select" type="radio" name="gender" value="function2"> Function2<br> 
  </form>
```

from the above form, the user will choose an option, based on that 'Button' value will be changed which is a 'function name' here.

```
  <button ng-click="this[choice.select]()">
    Button 
  </button>
```

**Working Jsfiddle here**: http://jsfiddle.net/mkarrfan/o89yguk9/